# MySQl cheapest color printer

Tags: mysql

Relations:

- Product(maker, model, type)
- Laptop(Model, price, speed, ram, hd, screen)
- PC(model, price, speed, ram, hd)
- Printer(model,price, color, price)

I am now trying to find the maker of the cheapest color printer

My Query:

```
SELECT maker FROM 
(SELECT model FROM printer NATURAL JOIN product WHERE printer.color = '1') AS t1  
WHERE price < all;
```

Comment: Can't you just order by price (asc), and limit your number of results to 1?

Comment: There is no maker in the printer relation. I need to join product and printer and then find the maker with the lowest price.

Comment: You do'nt need a subquery for this. A join will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it this way:

```
select distinct Pro.maker, Pri.price
from Product Pro join Printer Pri on Pro.model = Pri.model
where Pri.price = (select min(price) from Printer where color = 'y')  and Pri.color = 'y'
```

In subquery `(select min(price) from Printer where color = 'y')` we should specify that the price should be searched for color printers only.

What I don't like in this solution is that we have to make filtering for color printer twice:

- in subquery `(select min(price) from Printer where color = 'y')`
- in top query `... and Pri.color = 'y'`

Though I don't know how to get rid from specifying this in the two places.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT `p.maker`
      FROM `product` AS `p`
INNER JOIN printer as pr
     WHERE p.model = pr.model
  ORDER BY pr.price ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: there is no maker in the printer relation.

Comment: It is within a subquery. Once the natural join were to join the two relations then that relation (subquery) would have a maker in its relation.

Comment: What if there are 2 printers with the cheapest price though the same?

Answer (score 1):

Using a subquery you should solve that this way:

```
select pro.maker from printer pri
natural join product pro
where pri.color = '1'
  and pri.price <= all (select price from printer where pri.color = '1')
```

With a `LIMIT` clause:

```
select pro.maker from printer pri
natural join product pro
where pri.color = '1'
order by pri.price
limit 1
```

Comment: This condition `pri.price <= all (select price from printer)` will demand the lowest price for all printers, not only color printers. Taking into account that we have `where pri.color = '1'` in the query, the resultant set will be empty, as `pri.price <= all (select price from printer)` will give the price for the cheapest black-and-white printer which is cheaper than the color, and no color printer will be found with such a price.

Comment: About second solution: what if there are 2 different printers with equal price which turn out to be cheapest?

Comment: Fixed first query. Second one is not necessarily wrong as the OP specifically requested "the maker of the cheapest color printer" (note he is expecting one). Even if the question is wrong, then first solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql following query also works:

```
select b.maker, min(a.price) from printer a, product b 
where a.color = '1'
and a.model = b.model;
```

Comment: There is no maker in the printer relation.

Comment: Ah ok, I just looked at the oldest answer :) I will fix it in few minutes.

Comment: I did not know I can do it like this. I have been having beginner problems trying to refer to specific tables within a query. I did not know I can instantaniate (spelled...) a name for a table so that it can referred to. Can I also, as you have here, refer to a relation I have named (printer a) before I have named it, I take it?

Comment: Yes of course you can refer to relation aliases like this. Youn can try running above query directly into MySQL client and see if it gets you desired result or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct product.maker, price 
from printer
join product
on ( product.model=printer.model)
where color='y' and
price = (select min(price) from printer where color='y')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker, price 
FROM Printer 
JOIN Product 
ON Product.model=Printer.model 
WHERE Printer.color=1 
AND Printer.price=
(SELECT MIN(price) 
FROM Printer
WHERE color=1)
```

Right.

The result of Your query:

```
maker      price

D          270.0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
Select distinct maker,price from Product 
Join Printer on printer.color='y'and Product.model= Printer.model
group by Printer.model
having price = (select min(price) from Printer where color='y')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner but i tried like this

```
select distinct p.maker, pr.price from

(select maker, model from product)p

inner join 

(select model, price from printer where color='y' and price=(select min(price) from 
printer where color='y'))pr

on p.model=pr.model
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ‍product.maker, printer.price
from product join printer on product.model=printer.model
where price= (select min(price) from printer where color='y')
```

Answer (score -1):

There can be multiple solutions, below is also working.

Yo may try this,

```
select  top 1 t1.maker, t2.price from  product t1, printer t2
where t2.color = 'y'
and t1.model = t2.model order by t2.price
```